# Inconsistent byte order while examining memory of an integer and a char array

Tags: c, gdb, endianness

On a **little endian** machine I'm trying to examine the memory of the following variables using GDB.

```
int main()
{
      char buffer[4] = "1234";
      int value = 0x31323334;
          //ascii - "1 2 3 4"

      retun 0;
}
```

What I expected to see was :

For buffer variable - 0x34333231
For value variable - 0x34333231

However, GDB examine output is:

```
(gdb) show endian
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)

(gdb) x/w &value 
0x7fffffffe440: 0x31323334
(gdb) x/w buffer
0x7fffffffe444: 0x34333231
```

Why is there a difference in storing int and char array data in memory?
It looks like value variable is stored as big endian, am I missing something?

Comment: Two side notes about explicitly giving the size of the array. 1) `char` buffers are often used as null-terminated strings and you haven't left room for the terminator that is implicit in the literal string. 2) The compiler emits literal characters using the "execution charset" you specify and that might not always use one `char` per "character". So, omit explicit array sizes for literal strings. You would see the debugger also show the null terminator, along with the bytes from your chosen character encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `buffer` is the four bytes

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 0x31 | 0x32 | 0x33 | 0x34 |
+------+------+------+------+
^                           ^
|                           |
Low address                 High address
```

The variable `value` is the four bytes

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 0x34 | 0x33 | 0x32 | 0x31 |
+------+------+------+------+
^                           ^
|                           |
Low address                 High address
```

And the `x` command displays in the native byte order (little endian in your case), leading to the output you get.

Comment: Wow, strange... is there a reason for this?

Comment: @sergeyrar Yes there's a reason: `buffer` is an array, and the first element is *always* at the lowest address in memory. For other values, there is no such fixed rule (otherwise we wouldn't have all the endianness problems).